# What class in AEM implements javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher interface?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I am looking to write a custom renderer for AEM 6.2 and cannot seem to track down which class implements the javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher interface. Does anyone have any ideas or places to look? I am almost ready to just start unpacking all of the jars and doing a manual search, but that would take quite a bit of time, so I don't want to if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Apache Sling implements it... http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.engine/2.3.0/org/apache/sling/engine/impl/request/SlingRequestDispatcher.html

Hopefully this helps someone else looking to customize things!